# c# if timer's current time is greater than

Tags: c#, timer, stream, grpc, ienumerator

I am receiving a gRPC response stream and would like to invoke an action if a message is not received after 500ms. I was going to use the Stopwatch class but it is more for debugging and I was concerned that it might not be the most efficient method. I would like to do something within my existing method:

```
while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                    default(CancellationToken)))
                {

                }
```

Such that:

```
while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                    default(CancellationToken)))
                {
                    //Message received
                    //Begin some sort of timer
                    //If no other message has been received for 500ms, execute ExampleMethod()
                }
```

Comment: if timer's current time is greater than what?

Comment: 500ms, i.e if I haven’t received another message after 500ms...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the DateTime to a variable whenever you received a message and subtract old time from it in Timer to see how much time has passed since last message:

```
DateTime LastMsgTime = DateTime.MinValue;
Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 50, Enabled = false };
timer.Tick += (s,e) => 
{ 
    if((DateTime.Now- LastMsgTime).TotalMilliSeconds > 500)  
       {ExampleMethod(); timer.Enabled = false; }
};
while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                    default(CancellationToken)))
                {
                     LastMsgTime = DateTime.Now;
                    //Message received
                    timer.Enabled = true;
                }
```